# Script: Change extension Excel to CSV

Tags: excel, csv, unix, ksh

I would like to change the output of the following (output) files into *.csv*

[image: output]

Maybe the answer is obvious. I know there is a way, adding the extension *.csv* (under the output directory)

I haven´t build the script, I found a reference to **EXCEL**  (see the script below)

My question is if **EXCEL** has to do with the files are saved under that extension *.xsl*

Is there a way to change the extension of the output changing  **EXCEL** in the script?

The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/ksh
echo "==========================================="
echo "             STARTED                   "
echo "   ***   `date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S`     ***   "
echo ""

cmd=/usr/script/bin/ReportBatch
logon="12"
datetime=`date +%d%m%Y`

# Source variables
. /sb/plus_test2/plus_home/plus-config.sh
. /sb/plus_test2/plus_home/.kshrc

TempOut="/sb/plus_test2/plus_home/ADMIN/report_output/New_Treas_Gap_Curves"
Archive="/sb/plus_test2/plus_home/ADMIN/report_output/Archive"
copyDir1="/sb/plus_test2/plus_home/nt/Treasury/TreasuryDailyRiskNew"
copyDir2="/sb/plus_test2/plus_home/nt/Treasury/TreasuryRiskatcherReports"
copyDir3="/sb/plus_test2/plus_home/nt/Treasury/StiborTransReport"

TODAY=`date '+%d'`
MONTH=`date '+%m'`
YEAR=`date +%Y`
CALENDER=/sb/plus_test2/plus_home/ADMIN/Calendar/SWED.CSV
DATE=$YEAR$MONTH$TODAY


## REMOVE THE PREVIOUS SAVED FILES TO ARCHIVE ##
echo "INFO: CLEARING THE TEMP OUTPUT DIRECTORY," ${TempOut}
mv ${TempOut}/* ${Archive}
echo "INFO: Completed Moving Old Files "
echo "INFO: Starting Report Generation:"
echo ""


##      Added 20/01/2011        ##
#ReportBatch company < $KPADMINFILE GLOBAL_SCRIPT TrRisKatcher EXCEL ${TempOut}/TrRisKatcher


##  Added 07/06/2012 to prevent reports to run on weekdayholidays ##
if [ `grep StB $CALENDER | grep $DATE | wc -l` -eq 0 ]
then
        ## REPORT BATCH COMMANDS TO LAUNCH Tdr SCRIPTS ##
        ReportBatch company < $KPADMINFILE GLOBAL_SCRIPT TdrFinancials EXCEL ${TempOut}/TdrFinancials


       
        ReportBatch company < $KPADMINFILE REPORT STIBOR EXCEL ${TempOut}/StiborTransReport_$DATE


        ## COPY COMMANDS TO MOVE REPORTS TO nt ##
        cp ${TempOut}/Tdr* ${copyDir1}
        cp ${TempOut}/Stibor* ${copyDir3}

fi


## COPY COMMANDS TO MOVE REPORTS TO nt ##
#cp ${TempOut}/TrRisKatcher* ${copyDir2}

echo ""
echo "   ***          COMPLETE       ***   "
echo "   ***   `date +%y/%m/%d_%H:%M:%S`   ***   "
echo "============================================"
```

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to only change the file **name**, or the file **format**, from xls to csv?

Comment: You have supplied the _bash_ and _shell_ tags, but your script is a ksh script. Why?

Comment: Hello, tags corrected, my bad. The file format, from .xls to .csv

Comment: Sure, thanks for your time, as I wrote before I know how to solve doing something like: filename.xlsx >filename.csv I  just wondering why the person that wrote the code added EXCEL in the script. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't see how `filename.xlsx >filename.csv` could work, because it means that you need an **executable program** called `filename.xlsx`.

Comment: If you have libreoffice installed, try `libreoffice --convert-to csv foo.xls`